# How use CASE with GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to write a query giving the table getting from a `case` expression from a table with all the tables, but I get an error
"ORA- 00936 expression absente"

Here my query:

```
select table_name,
       case
         when table_name in ('SI_CONTRAT_EVT_F','SI_CONTRAT_EVT_PU_F')  then
          1
         else
          0
       end, 
from rgpd_table_param
where test = 1
group by
       table_name,
       case
         when table_name = 'SI_CONTRAT_EVT_F' then
          1
         else
          0
       end ;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `GROUP BY` here? You aren't performing any aggregations.

Answer (score 0):

A more readable alternative, that gets you identical results, is to move *that* `CASE ... END` expression to a new column, then `GROUP BY` that column by-name.

```
WITH q1 AS (

    SELECT
        table_name,
 /*     CASE WHEN table_name IN ( 'SI_CONTRAT_EVT_F','SI_CONTRAT_EVT_PU_F' ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, -- Commented out because this column isn't used anywhere. */
        CASE WHEN table_name = 'SI_CONTRAT_EVT_F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isEvtF
    FROM
        rgpd_table_param
    WHERE
        test = 1
)
SELECT
    table_name,
    isEvtF
FROM
    q1
GROUP BY
    table_name,
    isEvtF
```